# Excel AddIn in Excel 2011 for MAC

Tags: excel, macos, excel-addins, osx-lion

How do you create an AddIn for Excel, if I am using Excel (Office 2011) on my MAC Machine(OS X Lion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 2011 still does not have a "full-fledged AddIn-API" but most of the VBA interface is available and AppleScript is also supported... not an AddIn-API as with Office 2010 for Windows but you can create something close (depending on your goal)...

Comment: :( Thanks for the bit though.