# What's the difference between an MS Office Visual Studio Add-in, Shared Add-in, and Excel 2010 Add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, ms-office, add-in

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a new add-in for Excel. Ideally I would like it to work with Excel 2011 (Mac), 2010, and 2007.

There are three template options to choose from when I start a new C# project.

- (Office) Excel 2010 Add-in
- (Extensibility) Visual Studio Add-in
- (Extensibility) Shared Add-in

What are the differences between these template choices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MS. As the name implies, you probably want to use shared add-in.

- **Office Excel 2010 Add-in**

Creates an application-level add-in for Excel 2007 or Excel 2010. For more information, see Getting Started Programming Application-Level Add-Ins and Excel Solutions.

- **(Extensibility) Visual Studio Add-in**

Visual Studio Add-ins add functionality to the Visual Studio and Visual Studio Macros environments. For more information, see How to: Create an Add-In.

- **(Extensibility) Shared Add-in**

Shared Add-ins can add functionality to one or more Microsoft Office applications, as well as to Visual Studio. For more information, see How to: Create an Add-In.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx

Answer (score 1):

#1 and #3 will work for Windows machines, but straight from Geoff Darst of Microsoft's VSTO team, ["the .Net Development Platform and Visual Studio Tools For Office are Windows only."](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/fe26644b-83ae-4129-98f0-5842e98b7b30/)  You'll have to [code in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803286/excel-addin-in-excel-2011-for-mac) to get functionality across all three versions.

If you want to target just the Windows environment, make sure you target the 2007 version of Excel, as I don't believe solutions developed for Excel 2010 are backward compatible with Excel 2007.